# What is the Frechet derivative of $\cos(x(\cdot))$?

Tags: derivatives, optimal-control, frechet-derivative

> What is the Frechet derivative of $\cos(x(\cdot))$?

Let $f: C[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x(\cdot))$.

My approach: by the definition of Frechet derivative we need to consider
$$
f((x+h)(t)) - f(x(t))
$$
for $\forall x, h \in C[0,1]$. In our case:
$$
\cos((x+h)(t)) - \cos(x(t)) = \sin(x(t))h(t) + o(h) 
$$

is it correct or I misunderstood something?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Gary find Frechet's derivative of $cos(x(\cdot))$

Comment: What is $x$ in your question?

Comment: @Joe $x$ is the function

Comment: So $x$ is an arbitrary continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$, yes?

Comment: @Joe Yes, that's correct

Comment: Well, if $x$ is an arbitrary continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$, then the composition $\cos \circ x$ need not be differentiable. For instance, take  $x(t)$ to be $t$ for $0\le t\le1/2$, and $1-t$ for $1/2\le t\le 0$. You can check that the left-hand and right-hand derivatives of $\cos\circ x$ at $1/2$ do not agree, and hence $\cos \circ x$ is not differentiable at $1/2$. Here, I mean "differentiable" in the sense of ordinary calculus – but a function $f\in C[0,1]$ is Fréchet differentiable at a point iff it is in differentiable in the ordinary sense at that point.

Comment: Even if $\cos\circ x$ is assumed to be differentiable, you cannot find a nice formula for its derivative in general. If, however, you assume that $x$ is differentiable, then you can use the chain rule to compute $\cos \circ x$.